# Properly modifying text pulled from a game and returning it

Tags: javascript

I'm *really* new to Javascript, kinda just learned a little earlier today and been messing around with it, but I'm running into a few issues her and there. I'd appreciate help from some people that know their way around the code.

What's the best way to search a string for multiple words? I'm not completely sure how to explain what I mean, so I'll include my current test code and try to explain. I'm making an attached script to pull text from a text based game online, converting it to lowercase, and defining variables for the use of a money system that changes the input text. Once changes are made, I'm re-inputting the modified text into the game as a return.

```
let money = 0;
const modifier = (text) => {
  
  let modifiedText = text;
  const lowered = text.toLowerCase();
  let moneyChange = 0;
    
  // The text passed in is either the user's input or players output to modify.
  if(lowered.includes('take their money') || lowered.includes('take ' + 'money')) {    
      
    moneyChange = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
    if ((moneyChange) > 1) {
      console.log(moneyChange);
      money += moneyChange;
      modifiedText = `You find ${moneyChange} Credits. You now have ${money} Credits`;
      
    } else {
      modifiedText = 'You find nothing.';
      console.log(modifiedText);
    }
  }
    console.log(modifiedText);
    // You must return an object with the text property defined. 
    return {text: modifiedText};
}

modifier(text);
```

Currently, as you can see, I have to specifically type "Take their money" or "Take money" as an action before the text pulled is recognized as me taking money from someone or taking some in general. My main issue is that with how the game works, it's somewhat impossible to guess exactly how the input or output is going to come out. The way it works is that the game takes your character's action or speech that you type out, processes it via AI into it's own action or dialogue and generates procedural story to make more sense with the setting so that the player only has to type a vague idea of what's going to happen.

Here's an example:

```
There's a dead man on the street in front of you.
>loot him
You loot the man, digging through his pockets. You take some money from his wallet, but find nothing else.
```

The > is my only input and the rest is completely AI generated. My script looks through the AI result and , so I could look for every possible result, from "take his money" to "take her money" and so forth, but that's a little too much to bother with if there's an easier way. If I could have it search the result for specific words that may not be in the normal order and/or with other words in between. Like, it must contain the words "take" and "money" so that if the game says "You find some money, along with a gun. You take both", it recognizes that I'm taking the money. As well as the fact that I still need to write code for *every single other time I do anything with money*, such as buying things, and if I have to write every possible thing it's going to be a pain.

I know that it would be easier if this code was integrated into the game, but due to AI limitations, that kinda breaks how it works and it goes a little crazy... Any sort of help you can give me will be a help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to search a string which includes multiple sub-phrases, you can use `string.includes()` in a loop like shown below:

```js
function containsWords(string, words) {
    for (let i=0, len=string.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (!string.includes(words[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However you also mentioned

> *search the result for specific words that may not be in the normal order and/or with other words in between*

Which immediately brings to mind **regex**, a text and string matching technology. You can easily find tutorials for regex online, and [this live tester](https://regexr.com) is nice too.

I'll quickly build a search string to match "take *** money", where any word can be *** as a quick introduction and example to regex:

`/take .+ money/g`

Here it matches the specific string `take` , then `.+` matches one or more characters (the middle pronoun eg him/her), then matches  `money`.

Comment: I just implemented this, and it's working great! I'm going to mess around with a few things and see what I can do with regex now. Thank you for your help!